# Display Google map with cluster of markers from Firebase database

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database on Firebase with locations. I want to display this locations as cluster of markers when the user launches the map Activity.

The Map is displayed when that activity is launched, but I am unable to get any of the markers from Firebase to display as a cluster.

I have added my codes below:

```
private void displayLocations() {
    Firebase myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("MY_URL");
    // Get only latest logged locations - since 'START' button clicked
    Query queryRef = myFirebaseRef.orderByChild("city");
    // Add listener for a child added at the data at this location
    queryRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        LatLngBounds bounds;
        LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            Map data = (Map) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            //String timestamp = (String) data.get("timestamp");
            // Get recorded latitude and longitude
            Map  mCoordinate = (HashMap)data.get("address");
            double latitude = (double) (mCoordinate.get("lat"));
            double longitude = (double) (mCoordinate.get("lng"));

            // Create LatLng for each locations
            LatLng mLatlng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

            // Make sure the map boundary contains the location
            builder.include(mLatlng);
            bounds = builder.build();

            // Add a marker for each logged location
            MarkerOptions mMarkerOption = new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(mLatlng)
                    .title("Pub")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon_map));
            Marker mMarker = mMap.addMarker(mMarkerOption);
            markerList.add(mMarker);

            // Zoom map to the boundary that contains every logged location
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds,
                    MAP_ZOOM_LEVEL));

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }


    });
}
```

Comment: Why didn't you place any code inside your `onAddChildren`? Please note that `onAddChildren()` event not only triggered when there is a new node in your database, but also the initial synchronization. (The first time your app get data from Firebase Database it triger `onAddChildren()` event, whether its new data or old one)

Comment: Where the method displayLocations() is been called? Can you post full code?

Comment: @SureshKumar  this is my codes to where i invoke that method@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;


        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(50.0647, 19.9450);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Krackow"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));

        displayLocations();
    }